# .NET Compact Framework - Cookie-based Web Service access

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, cookiecontainer

I need to access Web Service from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application. Problem is that Web Service uses cookies for authentication. In desktop application I use .NETs CookieContainer(), which is missing in CF. How can I manage cookies in CF without CookieContainer?

Can someone give me a hand in solving this problem?
Thank you.
MattheW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. I found example posted by Alex Feinman (link below) extremely helpful. Take a look at his great solution if you encounter similar problem.

Regards, MattheW

http://groups.google.com/groups?threadm=OSxq7SlTEHA.1244%40TK2MSFTNGP10.phx.gbl

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to work directly with the cookie HTTP header.

This forum post has a reasonable code sample to get you started:

[Cookies in Compact Framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/34d88228-0b68-4fda-a8cd-58efe6b47958)

Take a look at this Wikipedia article for more general info on the Cookie HTTP header:

[HTTP Cookie - Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Cookie#Implementation)